# How to filter by description of document in Telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have this code:

```
def initiate_sticker_set(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(update.message.chat.id, "initiate sticker set")

initiate_sticker_set_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text("hello"), initiate_sticker_set)
dispatcher.add_handler(initiate_sticker_set_handler)
```

I want this Filter to catch not only plain text messages, but also documents with description "hello". How to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to capture for example png document with description "your_descpription" or "your_descpription2", use MessageHandler the following way:

```
initiate_sticker_set_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.caption(["your_descpription", "your_descpription2"]) & Filters.document.mime_type("image/png"), initiate_sticker_set)
dispatcher.add_handler(initiate_sticker_set_handler)
```